# How to use function class from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file called **Program_01.py** within the file, I've created 2 class called **Estadisticas** and **LecturaArchivo**. How to call the **function suma()** and **desviacionEstandar()** in the class Estadisticas from LecturaArchivo class. I've got a compilation error:

**NameError: name "media" is not defined**

For example:

```
print('Promedio: {:.2f}'.format(media(linkedList)))
print('Desviación Estándar: {:.2f}'.format(desviacionEstandar(linkedList)))
```

## Clase Lectura Archivo

```
class LecturaArchivo:
nombreArchivo = input('Nombre del archivo: ')
archivo = open(nombreArchivo, "r")
lineas = archivo.read()
datos = [dato.strip() for dato in lineas.split(',')]
linkedList = ListaEnlazada()

for dato in datos:
    linkedList.insertarFinal(float(dato))

print('Promedio: {:.2f}'.format(media(linkedList)))
print('Desviación Estándar: {:.2f}'.format(desviacionEstandar(linkedList)))
```

## Clase Estadisticas

```
class Estadisticas:
def suma(lista):
    resultado = 0
    for elemento in lista:
        resultado += elemento.dato
    return resultado

def media(lista):
    return suma(lista) / lista.tamanio

def desviacionEstandar(lista):
    resultado = 0
    listaMedia = media(lista)
    sqrtLista = ListaEnlazada()

    for elemento in lista:
        sqrtLista.append((elemento.dato - listaMedia) ** 2)
    return math.sqrt(suma(sqrtLista) / (lista.tamanio - 1 ))
```

Comment: `Estadisticas.media` and `Estadisticas.desviacionEstandar`

Comment: Now, I've got this compilation error:                                                     
  **File "Program_01.py", line 50 in media  return suma(lista) / lista.tamanio NameError: name "suma" is not defined**

Comment: It doesn't look like any of your classes are necessary. If you just delete the `class` lines, then it would probably work fine. Why are you using classes here? You don't appear to be creating any instances, nor are your functions written to work as methods. If you don't know how classes work, you may want to read a tutorial on that, rather than just throwing them into your code randomly without understanding their purpose. [The Official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) does a decent job of explaining the basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LecturaArchivo(Estadisticas):
```

i think just a `def` will work here, i'm not seeing a need of `class`
and the formatacion should be revised